# Update to Welcome Message

Tags: discussion

The main site FAQ ([FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)) has quite a few good resource perhaps we can link to from our Welcome message. E.g. under "Asking a Good Question"

Maybe we can also have master collection of links like the main sites FAQ.